# How to get alternative translations using Microsoft Translator API GetTranslations

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-translator

I would like to read  alternative text translations for a given word using the getTranslations API. The web response status code looks OK but the response stream returns as null. Does anyone have a working example or point what's wrong with my code? Appreciate your help.

```
string uri = string.Format("https://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/GetTranslation?         
text=Origin&from=es&to=de&maxTranslations=10");
WebRequest translationWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
                translationWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", 
                 tokenProvider.GetAccessToken());
WebResponse response = null;
response = translationWebRequest.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the new Microsoft Translator Text API v3 which includes a multi-lingual dictionary API. The v2 to v3 migration documentation is at [www.aka.ms/Translatorv3Migration](http://www.aka.ms/Translatorv3Migration).

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for information. I shall try Dictionary lookup Api and keep posted. BTW I tried the GetTranslations API using Ajax and it workes for me. But I'm still seeing only one translation string. I also tried by setting optional parameter  "IncludeMultipleMTAlternatives" but no difference in the results.This is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

v3 is REST and JSON only. Dictionary documentation is in the [v3 documentation](http://aka.ms/Translatorv3Docs).